# How can I get the ECID of a connected device using libimobiledevice?

Tags: c, libimobiledevice

Using libimobiledevice I can get the ECID of a connected device from the command line by running

```
$ ideviceinfo -k UniqueChipID
```

Is there a way to do this using the C API?

Comment: Why not look at how [ideviceinfo itself](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/tools/ideviceinfo.c) does it? It's only two hundred lines of C, most of it command-line argument parsing; and it uses the C API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `lockdownd_get_value`, which is part of the libimobiledevice C api. The declaration is:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a preferences plist using an optional domain and/or key name.
 *
 * @param client An initialized lockdownd client.
 * @param domain The domain to query on or NULL for global domain
 * @param key The key name to request or NULL to query for all keys
 * @param value A plist node representing the result value node
 *
 * @return LOCKDOWN_E_SUCCESS on success, LOCKDOWN_E_INVALID_ARG when client is NULL
 */
LIBIMOBILEDEVICE_API_MSC lockdownd_error_t lockdownd_get_value(lockdownd_client_t client, const char *domain, const char *key, plist_t *value);
```

You can create a `lockdown_client_t` using a `lockdownd_client_new`. Look at the `ideviceinfo` source code for more information on how to set up a lockdown client.

The `domain` and `key` parameters map to what you've provided on the command line. You didn't specify a domain, so set that to `NULL`. `key` should be the value of what you passed as the `-k` argument, hence `UniqueChipID`.

The output will be a `plist_t`. You can use the  libplist API to convert this to XML or a string.

Comment: How can I convert the `plist_t` to a String with libplist?

Comment: Use `plist_get_string_val`, this function allows you to pass a `plist_t` and convert it to a `char*`